# Comparing dynamic arrays together with an if then else statement

Tags: php, arrays, compare

In my code I want to replace the following:

```
if($file['domain']=="VALUE" || $file['domain']=="VALUE" || $file['domain']=="VALUE" || $file['domain']=="VALUE"){}
else{}
```

with something like this that can be changed in a more generic config file:

```
$domains_to_exclude="VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE";
```

The values of both arrays change and vary. What I want to do is if the `$file['domain']` matches the value of `domains_to_exclude` is to skip over it.

I am going in the right direction by trying something like this. So far I've not had any success.

```
$myArray = explode(',', $domains_to_exclude);
$count = count($file);
for ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++)
{
  if ($myArray[$i] !== $file['domain'])
  {
    $domain=$file['domain'];
    $domainn = str_replace("", "", $domain);
    echo'<option value="'.$domain.'">'.$domainn.'</option>';
  }
  else {}
}
```

Comment: `in_array` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myArray = explode(',', $domains_to_exclude);
if (!in_array($file['domain'], $myArray)) {
    // Domain is ok, process file
}
```

in_array($str, $arr) checks if any of the values in $arr equals $str.

And also, you don't have to have that else block there if it is empty. But it won't affect your code negatively either.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
$domains_to_exclude = array(...); //make an array of your "VALUES"

$file = array('foo', 'bar'); // your $file array

if(count(array_intersect($domains_to_exclude, $file)) > 0){
    // at least a match was found
 }
```